# Proof using only positivity axioms

Tags: abstract-algebra

> **Positivity Axioms**
>   Let $\mathscr{P}$ be the set of positive real numbers.
>   (i) For $a,b \in \mathscr{P}$, $a+b \in \mathscr{P}$ and $ab \in \mathscr{P}$
>   (ii) For $a$ a real number only one of the three is true: $a \in \mathscr{P}$, $-a \in \mathscr{P}$, or $a=0$.

I want to show that for $a<b$ and $c<d$, $a+c < b+d$.

Since $a<b$, then $b-a \in \mathscr{P}$ and $d-c \in \mathscr{P}$.
Then $(b-a)+(d-c) \in \mathscr{P}$.

Ideally I would want to say: $(b+d)-(a+c) \in \mathscr{P}$.  So $a+c<b+d$.
Is this proof correct?

Comment: By commutativity,associativity of addition, and properties of additive inverse, this is clear.

Comment: Any subset of $\Bbb{R}$, including $\mathscr{P}$, inherits the axioms involving the universally quantified algebraic properties of $+,*$ including those listed by André.

Comment: I guess I was worried because of the order in which Royden introduced these axioms - Positivity, then Field, then Completeness.

Comment: Ah, I assumed you were talking about Royden, so I opened up my copy of the Third edition where he introduces the Field axioms before the "Order axioms" (positivity).

Comment: @peoplepower I think Fitzpatrick rearranged Royden to have the positivity axioms come first.  It's odd since we are talking about elements in $\mathbb{R}$ - so I  should be able to use my knowledge of fields.